# Using Flexbox and I want to make a box posistioned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
    margin: 10px auto; 
   
}
body {
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
   font-size: 100%;
   margin: 10px 10px
} 
#main {
   display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   display: -moz-box;  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
   display: flex;       /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   text-align:center ;    
   width: 50 %;
    
}
#top_header {
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -ms-flex-order: 1;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  -webkit-order: 1;               /* NEW - Chrome */
  order: 1;                 /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */ 
   border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 25px;
 box-shadow: rgb (110,110,110) 8px 8px 8px;
   background:gray;
   padding: 20px;
   margin:0px;
   width:100%; 
   font: bold 1.5em Gothic; 
} 

#top_menu { 
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -ms-flex-order: 2;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    -webkit-order: 2;               /* NEW - Chrome */
    order: 2;                   /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+*/ 
 content-align:center; 
 width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px; 
 padding-right: 10px;
    border: black;
 border-radius: 25px;
 box-shadow: rgb (110,110,110) 8px 8px 8px;
 background: #9595FD;
 content: center; 
} 
#top_menu li {
   display:inline-block; /* inline means it displays left to right */ 
   text-align: left; 
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 font: bold 1em tahoma; 
 content: center; 
 background: #C0C0C0;
}
#main_section   {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -ms-flex-order: 4;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  -webkit-order: 4;               /* NEW - Chrome */
   order: 4;           /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   flex: 1; 
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 25px;
 box-shadow: rgb (110,110,110) 8px 8px 8px;
   background:gray;
   width:20%;
   height: 100% ; 
    
} 
#recent_news   {
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 5;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
   -ms-flex-order: 5;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   -webkit-order: 5;               /* NEW - Chrome */
   order: 5; 
    /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-shadow: rgb (110,110,110) 8px 8px 8px;
   background:white;
   width: 10%; 
   height: 100%; 
   margin:10px; 
} 
#other_stuff   { 
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
   -ms-flex-order: 3;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   -webkit-order: 3;               /* NEW - Chrome */
   order: 3;        /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 25px;
 box-shadow: rgb (110,110,110) 8px 8px 8px;
   background:white;
   width: 10% ;
   height: 100% ; 
   margin: 10px;
    
   
   
} 
#footer   {
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6; 
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 6;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
   -ms-flex-order: 6;              /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   -webkit-order: 6;               /* NEW - Chrome */
   order: 6;                       /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   border-top: 2px solid black;
   background: white;
   padding: 5px;
   margin:10px;
   text-align:center;
   width: 100% ; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources Page.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="main">
  <header id="top_header">
   
  </header>
  <nav id="top_menu">
   
  </nav>
  <section id="main_section">
    
   <article class="article">
    
    
   <footer>
    <p></p>
   </footer>
   </article>
   
  </section>
        <aside id="recent_news">
        </aside>
  <aside id="other_stuff">
     </aside>
  <footer id="footer">
  <p></p> 
  </footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Say I wanted `#other_stuff` to become fixed so that if `main_section` was a long list of things and the recent news box was say, a quick search bar, it would scroll down along side with you so you do not have to scroll all the way back to the top to quickly navigate to something (since that would defeat the purpose of having a quick nav bar).

Can I add something to this to make it stay along side the left of the main section? I do not know if a fixed position is what I am looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you're asking for is to make a div or element stop once it reaches the top of the screen while you're scrolling. While using `flex` in your design, I wont say it's impossible, but it will be difficult to you use `postion: fixed;` because the other elements want to shift and move to fill the space. Also, you'll most certainly need to use some sort of JavaScript along with what you have so that it can scroll first and then stick. I've put together a [jsFiddle that shows how to do the sticky div part](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/7bxLm/).